# why this tensorflow model cost is maximized not minimized?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

iam beginner in tensorflow and i want to implement model to recognize rgb of any pixel of new greyscale image, so i trained it in greyscale images pixels with thier colored pixels but the cost is maximized not minimized , so what is wrong with my logic or code?

```
n_nodes_hl1 = 50
n_outputs = 3
x = tf.placeholder('float',[1,1])#pixel in gray
y = tf.placeholder('float',[1,3])# rgb chanels

def neural_network_model(data):
hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}


output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_outputs])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_outputs])),}

l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

output = tf.matmul(l1,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

return output
#=======================================
def train_neural_network():
prediction = neural_network_model(x)
cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

nm_epochs = 500
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(nm_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for i in range(len(images_grey)):
            for xx in range(images_grey[i].width):
                for yy in range(images_grey[i].height):                       
                     _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: np.reshape(images_grey[i].getpixel((xx,yy)),[1,1]), y:np.reshape(images_colored[i].getpixel((xx,yy)),[1,3])})
                     epoch_loss += c
        print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',nm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

train_neural_network()
```

and images_colored = [], images_grey = [] are filled with image from another function.

Comment: What makes you think the `cost` is maximized and not minimized? Have you observed increase of the `cost`?

Comment: And why are your "images" `1x1` and `1x3`?

Comment: Oh, and you __add__ the cost from every iteration... it's not strange the accumulator is increasing...

Comment: yes when i see the output in console " print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',nm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss) " the epoch loss is increased all the epochs
and 1*1 for 1 pixel at time , 1*3 for rgb outputs

Comment: No no i intialize it with zero every epoch.

Comment: I see. Anyway, you should pass the whole image to the network together, right now you're training a model for a single pixel.

Comment: right now, i trained it for the whole image and it is decreased for many iterations and then increased again the rest of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the learning curve you are facing and appreciate you sharing your model for this problem. Can you try plotting the predicted image every few epochs in your training loop:

```
n_iterations = 500
batch_size = 50
with tf.Session() as sess:
# Here we tell tensorflow that we want to initialize all
# the variables in the graph so we can use them
# This will set W and b to their initial random normal value.
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# We now run a loop over epochs
prev_training_cost = 0.0
for it_i in range(n_iterations):
    idxs = np.random.permutation(range(len(xs)))
    n_batches = len(idxs) // batch_size
    for batch_i in range(n_batches):
        idxs_i = idxs[batch_i * batch_size: (batch_i + 1) * batch_size]
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: xs[idxs_i], Y: ys[idxs_i]})

    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: xs, Y: ys})
    print(it_i, training_cost)

    if (it_i + 1) % 20 == 0:
        ys_pred = Y_pred.eval(feed_dict={X: xs}, session=sess)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        img = np.clip(ys_pred.reshape(img.shape), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()
```

I have worked through a free online course under Parag K Mital that I think you may find useful in your journey.  There is a particular lecture where you train a network to paint a RBG image (lecture2).  You can vary the network size and learning rate and progressively see how the network performs:

https://github.com/pkmital/CADL/blob/master/session-2/lecture-2.ipynb

Depending on the image domain (e.g. faces) a deep network trained on a representative data set may offer superior performance and be able to better predict the RBG value for each pixel based on the gray scale intensity values.  The videos may also be helpful as Parag does a really good job of breaking down the concepts.

Let me know if this resource proves helpful and good luck!